# Lucene set document id

Tags: lucene

I wonder is it possible to set document id by hands? I.e. I want to use lucene as an index search only. So I have some kind of id -> text mapping already in application and want my search to return matched my ids.

I understand that I can:
search -> get lucene generated ids -> search by these ids -> get my id as a document field.
But why should I do extra operation which I do not really need?

Comment: To some kind of comment my own question: Lucene DocIds are NOT something you can rely on - they are internal to lucene and can be changed with time, which means you cannot assign those. However to save time when you search doc content by lucene DocId - you might  have some cache if your documents are add-only and there are no merges happen. This is no guaranteed but currently if there are no deletions - this should work.